# How to prevent a user from entering in a blank line in c++

Tags: visual-c++, input

I am working on a program  where the user inputs data. I made it so the user could not enter in spaces when entering in their first and last name but now the user can now just enter in a blank line for their input here's a sample of my code

```
cout<<"Enter in your first name"<<endl;
getline(cin,fname);
while( fname.find(' ')!=string::npos){

        cout<<"Name can't have spaces"<<endl;
        getline(cin,fname);




 }
```

I'm just wonder how I prevent the user from entering in a blank line for in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a loop, and if the user does enter a blank line then go back and ask them for input again.

Comment: A basic loop looks like `while (1) { /* your code goes here */}`.  In the "your code goes here" bit, check if the string is empty or not (`fname.empty()`) . If it is not empty then `break;` out of the loop, otherwise ask the user to enter something again.